# Does $f(x)\in\mathbb P$ for polynomial $f$ and some $x>0$ imply infinitely many prime $f(x)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $$f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{k} a_n x^n$$ be some non-constant polynomial where all coefficients $a_n$ are nonnegative integers except for the constant term $a_0$, which must be positive.

Assuming the [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture), if $f(c)$ is prime for some integer $c>0$, would it follow that $f(x)$ yields infinitely many primes?

Comment: So basically, you're asking if a non-constant polynomial $f$, with non-negative integer coefficients, and where $f(n)$ is a prime for some positive integer $n$, fulfills the three criteria given in that Wikipedia article?

Comment: No, think of $X^4+X^2+1$, $n=1$.

Comment: @Arthur Essentially, yeah, I guess I am, although I added another similar question.

Comment: @Mindlack That has $0$-valued coefficients with $n=1$, so wouldn't apply to either case.

Comment: Trev: then you’ll want to change your notation, I took $k=2$, $a_n=2n$, $c_n=1$.

Comment: $f(x) = 2x$....

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

$f(x)$ must be strictly increasing given the constraints. If $f(c)$ is prime and $c>0$, then since $f(0)<f(c)$, we know $f(c) \nmid f(0)$ and $f(0)$ must be relatively prime to $f(c)$, thus fulfilling the requirements of the Bunyakovsky conjecture.

Comment: You are not addressing the irreducibility part, though...

Comment: If $f(x)$ were reducible, some $k$ would always divide it, so you couldn't have two different values which were relatively prime.

Comment: Not necessarily, you could have factors with negative coefficients that take the value $1$ several times. Example: $X^4+X^2+1$ for $X=1,3$.